# C programming - analyzing a line

Tags: c

If I have 3 source like "a  b  c", how do I separate a from b from c?

```
struct target *t = target_start;
    char *source_start = p_colon+1;
    while (*source_start == ' ' || *source_start == '\t')
      { source_start++; }
    char *source_end = source_start;
    while (*source_end == ' ' || *source_end == '\t')
      { source_end--; }
    char *p_space = strchr(source_start,' ');
    //while(p_space != NULL)

//list_sources_append(&sources, source_start);
list_targets_append(&sources, t->source = source_start);
source_end++;
*source_end = '\0';
```

Comment: it would be better to use [`isspace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace) to determine if `*source_start` is whitespace.

Comment: @TimothyJones - I agree, but do keep in mind that `isspace` counts newlines. Something to be taken into account if line breaks need to be handled separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use isspace(), that should do it.

Answer (score 4):

Lookup the strtok() function to break a string into a series of tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file names are separated by whitespace, and don't contain any whitespace, the easiest way is probably with `sscanf(input, "%s %s %s", a, b, c);`